# BaseX Access from JAVA

Tags: java, basex

This is a very basic question, but I can't seem to find an answer.  I've just installed BaseX (V.7.8.1 on Win7 PRO/64- bit) and have it running successfully through their GUI.  I am now trying to run queries locally via their JAVA examples (from GitHub - specifically their RunQueries.java example).  I've created a test project in Eclipse and placed the RunQueries.java code there to try to run it.  But, the BaseX imports are not being resolved :

```
import org.basex.core.*;
import org.basex.core.cmd.*;
import org.basex.data.*;
import org.basex.io.serial.*;
import org.basex.query.*; 
import org.basex.query.iter.*;
import org.basex.query.value.item.*;
```

Should the general install of BaseX put these packages in the correct place?  If not, what do I need to do to find & get these package components properly into my directory structure?  Appreciate any help.

Comment: Probably the only `noSQL` datastore which interests me; so, good q.  I'd be interested to hear use cases.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `BaseX.jar` file as an external JAR to your Eclipse project. You can do this by right-clicking on your project in `Package Explorer`, then `Build Path > Add External Archives`. I am assuming you also run their GUI from this JAR file, so you should have it. If not, you can download it [here](http://basex.org/products/download/all-downloads/).

If you are also interested in the internal workings of BaseX; you can actually download their source from [GitHub](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex).